# C# Syntax Question on Question Mark and Colon

Tags: c#, syntax

There are several statements in an existing project that includes `?` and `:`.

I would like to understand what do they mean, and in the following statements, if they can be explained.

```
loginID = rawLoginID.Contains("\\") ? rawLoginID : domain + "\\" + rawLoginID;

string orgUnitCode = row[ORG_UNIT_CODE] != null
                     ? row[ORG_UNIT_CODE].ToString()
                     : string.Empty;

loginID = loginID.Contains("\\") ? loginID : domain + "\\" + loginID;
```

The syntax that I am not sure are `?` `:`

Thank you.

Comment: Documentation is usually the best place to start, the operators are called ternerary operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: Thank you @peeyushsingh. I will read the documentation.