# c# code is unity, that I couldn't understand

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I really need someone to explain this part of code  `float x  = Random.Range(0,2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;` I understand that it generates a random value of either 1 and -1, and that this `float x  = Random.Range(0,2)` give x a value between 0 and 2, but what does this `== 0 ? -1 : 1;` do, and how does it function?

Comment: Don't use the `unityscript` tag since the JavaScript-like language has been obsolete for sometime now.

Comment: It means `float x; if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 0) { x = -1; } else { x = 1; }`.

Comment: Other dup-targets: [Question mark and colon in statement. What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6957214/8967612), [C# Syntax Question on Question Mark and Colon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56436554/8967612)

Answer (score 0):

This is [the conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

The code is equivalent with:

```
float r =  Random.Range(0,2);
float x;

if (r == 0)
    x = -1;
else
    x = 1;
```

With the conditional operator `x` can be initialized while with the equivalent `if` code I show `x` must be assigned after initialization. This doesn't matter for `float` but for other types it may matter.

Answer (score 0):

As you said `Random.Range(0,2)` gives a value between 0 and 2. The question mark in this variable assignment is called a ternary operator and works like this: `condition ? assign this value if true : assign this value if false`.

So in your case if it equals 0, x will be set to -1, if it does not it will equal 1

You can find out more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), at the official Microsoft docs

Answer (score 0):

A question mark and colon in this circumstance is an inline `if` statement using the [“ternary conditional operator”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

It acts similarly to an `if` statement but within a larger statement on a single line. For example this:

```
if( a > b )
    largest = a;
else
    largest = b;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
largest = ( a > b ? a : b );
```

If the conditional statement before the `?` is `true`, the whole clause will become the value immediately after the question mark. If the conditional statement before the `?` is `false`, the whole clause will become the value immediately after the colon (`:`).

You can use more than one of them in a line, for example:

```
bool a = false;
int i = 3;
Console.WriteLine(“a is “ + ( a ? “true” : “not true” ) + “ and i is “ + ( i == 3 ? “three” : “not three” ) + “!”);
```

Note that the “else” is not optional.

So in effect the code you posted is saying “if the random number == 0, x=-1, else x=1”.

Answer (score 0):

It is ternary operator, it is similar to if else condition.

For example if you write `var x = random == 0 ? -1 : 1;` then in terms of if else condition it will be

```
if(random == 0)
{
  x = -1;
}
else 
{
  x = 1;
}
```